# ESXi / Networking / security

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm designing a VMware 5.5 infra, from memory and the course notes, I'm struggling around the networking, I know the management network, vmotion network and NFS all have to be on separate networks.

Couple of questions:

Do the above need to be separate vlan's and away from the other networks or is that important.
Do the ESXI hosts need to be on a secure DMZ vlan. We have a very secure network as it is, maybe its not necessary but these will be our mission critical servers, and the business depends on them being up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how far you want to take it...

This is less of a ESX question and more of general networking.

Vlans if enforced properly are secure and if you put management on a separate VLAN, it will be isolated from the main data network.

Just make sure you don't mess up your trunk ports and send a trunk to the ESXi data port that has management traffic.

I am not aware of any ESXi network security breaches/problems in the wild (not saying there are any), but, if anyone managed to make a privilege escalation type attack that went from VM to host, quite frankly, with root access to an ESX box, they would be able to get in to the management network or any other network connected to the box anyway.